# Logo above header image(slide show)

Tags: html, css, image, slideshow

I am struggling with CSS. I have got a simple slide show and I want, that my logo is above of it.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="header">
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <div id="grafic">
            <img id="bild" src="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

and my CSS:

```
#header {
width: 100%;
height: 350px;
/*background-image: url(../pics/header.png);*/
}

#logo {
height: 320px;
background-image: url(../pics/jobber_logo.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:50px 45px;
float: left;
z-index: 10;    
}

#grafic {
z-index: 1;
}

#bild {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Here is a Link for understanding: [header](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3904/iuk8kde8_jpg.htm)

I am  a bit confused!!

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure on what you're requesting here but here's a quick guess.

Your #grafic container needs to clear the float that you've set on the #logo container.

Try updating your #grafic selector to the following:

```
#grafic {
    clear: left;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

This will force the #grafic to move below your #logo.

Here's a great article (very old but still relevant) on understanding how CSS Float works. http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: I have updated my post, there is an image. Maby you can understand my problem better now.

Comment: Ah I understand now - you want the logo to sit on top of the slideshow. W Van Rij 's comment below would be the correct way to achieve this. You just need to add the position absolute property.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
position: absolute;
```

In order an element to "float" above an other. Add the position tag on your logo.

Reference material: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp